# Broadcast to directive from modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-bootstrap

I am using angularjs directive which contains some methods with ajax call in broadcasting event.
I am passing data as parameter to directive from different controllers ,some data I am passing from modal to directive as well.But I am able not pass data to directive from modal only.What I have did wrong I am not getting it other pages are working fine but issue only with the modal controller .
Please refer jsfiddle

Comment: you should share some code so you can get better answers.

Comment: Please refer jsfiddle for code -  https://jsfiddle.net/e4yo10sx/

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing arguments in :

```
 $rootScope.$on(
       'refreshCharts',
       function(e, data) {
                  console.log(data);
        }
```

Comment: If I pass argument or not still not works .Its not getting udpated $scope.sendData values

Comment: Please have look on broadcast/on with $rootscope declarations , its slightly different with $scope:
https://toddmotto.com/all-about-angulars-emit-broadcast-on-publish-subscribing/

Comment: Thank you D.Pareek for your reference link ,As I opened modal means sibling controller and broadcasting to directive using broadcast event with correct method still not able to resolve problem.